# Addition operation with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: http-post, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am trying to make addition operation with ASP.NET Core Web API post method but n1 and n2 are always zero

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("sum")]
        public ActionResult<int> sum([FromForm] ToplamaModel model)
        {
            int sonuc = model.n1 + model.n2;

            return sonuc;
        }
    }

    public class ToplamaModel
    {
        public int n1 { get; set; }
        public int n2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

API link: https://localhost:7070/api/values/sum

Raw json message:

```
{ "Sayi1": 5, "Sayi2": 3 }
```

I am using Postman to test

I asked chat gpt and its say change FromForm to FromBody but that didn't work and instead returns:

```
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
"title": "Unsupported Media Type",
"status": 415,
"traceId": "00-005af8933c5749315192cbff0b3953e0-86195ee93a314294-00"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [FromBody] as your data are in body, not form.

You got "Unsupported Media Type" because you probably turned off the header "Content-Type" in "Headers" tab in Postman. It should be turned on and have a value of "application/json".

And finally, your json should be: `{"n1": 5,"n2": 3}`, so it can be deserialized properly to your ToplamaModel object.

Comment: Content-Type in Headers is on and even is off nothing change

Comment: Have you changed your json to ```{"n1": 5,"n2": 3}```?

Comment: Yes I changed as you say

Comment: in Postman, when you enter your json ("Body" tab), "raw" must be selected, and from drop down box you should select "JSON" (not "Text" or "JavaScript").

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make addition operation with ASP.NET Core Web API post
> method but n1 and n2 are always zero

I have tested using your sample with `[FromForm]` and I am getting exact output. Its not sure how did you sent your request from postman. However, this can be achieved either using `[FromForm]` and `[FromBody]` in that scenario, request pattern would be changed a bit.

**[FromForm] :**

I have tried as following for `[FromForm]`:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**[FromBody] :**

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("sum")]
    public ActionResult<int> sum([FromBody] ToplamaModel model)
    {
        int sonuc = model.n1 + model.n2;

        return sonuc;
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you want to use FromBody use replace it within your method signature. Rest of the syntax would remain same.

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#binding-source-parameter-inference) for more details.